# Difference between .on() vs .one() vs .trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery

What are the significant differences between these functions? On what basis to decide, which of these to use?

Comment: come on, jquery has one of the best documentations out there. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`on` is used to attach a function to an event, on some element(s).
http://api.jquery.com/on/

`one` does the same, but as soon as it is run once, the action is unbinded.
http://api.jquery.com/one/

`trigger` triggers an event on any element.
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

> On what basis to decide, which of these to use?

It's like asking `On what basis do I decide, whether I need to buy nails, clothes or sunglasses`?

You're looking at it the wrong way around. Usually, you have an idea what you want to accomplish, then it's quite clear which one of these functions you need. After all, they do very different things.

If you can't decide which one to use, you've deeply misunderstood something or you don't know yet what you're trying to do and think that some magical function call can solve your situation.

Thus, think hard about your problem. What is it supposed to do? Once you're fully aware of your situation, the choice is **obvious**.